# updating adapter by data from ListView (not the opposite)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a long ListView, which its items are editable (simple strings).
The user can change the content as he/she wants.

My problem is, that when I want to retrieve the new data from the List view,
I can not reach the invisible items in the list.

How can I retrieve the data from these items **without scrolling to these items**?

Is there a way to fill the adapter ,with the new data the user entered to the list?

Comment: Whatever way it may be , but fundamentally your list adapter must have all the data that will be shown on view. I don't understand why you can not access those items which are still not rendered. You are getting this list from some other source?

Comment: @ theJango Hi, I replied in your seperated question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that. if you have reference of Adapter for that list view
you can call `getCount` and then iterate and while calling `getItem(pos)` , to get data for all the positions in the list view.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a reference of Adapter of that list view, but the problem is that this adapter hold the old data, and I am interested in the new data, that in the list view. Please remember the list view is editable, so the user may change it a second ago, and this data is not in the adapter. The data I need is only in the list view.